# Does the Steam overlay hog resources?

Tags: steam

I'm running on an older machine so resources are limited; this is *not* a gaming rig.  As such, I'm trying to maximize system resources by turning off unnecessary things.

Does the Steam overlay consume additional resources?  I assume it must, but how much?  Is there a process I can monitor in Task Manager to see RAM allocation?  Is there a way to disable the Steam overlay entirely?

Comment: Yeah, there's a process in windows called gameoverlay or steamoverlaygui or something like that, should be pretty easy to monitor (and you can just close it from there, if you'd like).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The separate process which handles the overlay is called `GameOverlayUI.exe` on Windows, and `gameoverlayui` on Mac. [Don't know yet for Linux.] If the overlay is disabled, *or if the overlay does not recognize/support the game window,* then the overlay process will not even be running.

The overlay can be disabled per-game or everywhere:

- For an individual game, select the game in Steam and go to **Properties → General → Enable Steam Community In-Game**. This option is *not* available for shortcuts to “non-Steam games”.
- For all of Steam, go to **Settings** (or **Preferences** on Mac) **→ In-Game → Enable Steam Community In-Game**.

Comment: If you turn off the overlay does that actually not run the associated program or does it just not bind Shift+Tab (or whatever) to show/hide it?

Comment: @NickT Good question. I'll check that too. I expect it would, since  for some “non-Steam games” the overlay can actually cause crashes.